# How to find a static IP and MAC address(or a device that reject any request like ping) on a network

Tags: router, static-ip, openwrt

I have a windows 10 PC and if I enable network discovery or set a static IP to the PC I'm not able to find it's IP address or MAC address from my OpenWRT router using arp table or dhcp.lease. Like I said I have OpenWRT router so I don't have so much space on the disk(only 1MB). The question is, is there any tool that doesn't use disk space higher than 1MB(or any another way) to find the IP address and it's MAC address.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

That because when you set static ip on the PC, OpenWRT are not noticed anymore of the WIN10 host information; Anyway if you try to ping that WIN10 host it should appear at least in to the ARP table of your OpenWRT router.

In my opinion, a better way to let computer take same ip always in to a network were a DHPC server is available is to use reservation of DHCP leases instead configure it manually in to the host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know the PC's IP address. I mean I have many routers and random devices connecting to it. So I think I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arp-scan` utility which already present on the open-wrt site.

Like wrote in previous answer you can ping hosts of entire network and collect needed MAC addresses from `arp` table.